# How to import 'org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender' jar to Grails project?

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm trying to use a custom jdbcappender in my Grails project. I downloaded the jar, added it in the lib folder and refresh the dependencies. When i used the custom appender got this error:

> No such property: URL for class: org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender

In this code:

```
appender new org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender(
        name: "stacktrace",
        URL: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test",
        user: "test",
        password: "test",
        dbclass: "org.postgresql.Driver",
        sql: "INSERT INTO audit VALUES('@MSG@','@THROWABLE@');"
    )
```

Is the error in the jar import or in the appender configuration?

Best Regards,

André Cruz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` (which is the standard JDBCAppender class in the Log4j jar) has a `setURL` method, but you're using `org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender` which has a `setUrl` method, so that line should be

```
url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test",
```

Comment: Hi Burt, this was the problem and i had to change 'user' to 'username' too. Thanks for the help and congratulations for the contributions over the Grails community. Appreciate ur job.